# What is the point of a constraint expression on a non-templated function?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

[temp.constr.decl] says that we can constrain a template or a function with a *constraint expression*.

Declarators [dcl.decl] tells us that, for functions, we may add an optional *trailing requires clause* to constrain it, and the standard [draft n4820](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4820.pdf) even gives these (seemingly pointless) examples:

```
void f1(int a) requires true;
auto f2(int a) -> bool requires true;
```

I understand that constraining a template or a concept is useful, but I fail to see how these constraints are useful for non-templated functions. **What's the point of constraining a non-templated function?**

Comment: C++20 final draft (n4860) forbade this on non-templated context (e.g. free functions). GCC 12 also complains. Constrained non-template member function in a class template is still allowed even if the `constraint-expression` is not parameterized by the template parameters of class template.

Comment: N4860 § 9.3 `4 The optional requires-clause (13.1) in an init-declarator or member-declarator shall be present only if the
declarator declares a templated function (9.3.3.5).` and in example `void f1(int a) requires true; // error: non-templated function`

Comment: @courage when I asked this question, that language wasn't present in the standard draft!

Comment: @AndyG I know and I didn't mean to blame you. It is just a complement for those who are confused when the compiler rejects such usage (e.g. me), so that people clicking into this question know constraints on non-templated function was NOT introduced into C++20 finally.

Comment: @courage: I think your comment would have better visibility as an answer. Go ahead and post. Guaranteed at least one upvote from me :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One of the main points of constraining non-template functions is to be able to write constraints to non-template members of template classes. For example, you might have some type like this:

```
template<typename T>
class value
{
public:
  value(const T& t);
  value(T&& t);

private:
  T t_;
};
```

Now, you want `value` to be copyable/moveable from `T`. But really, you want it to be copyable/moveable from `T` *only* as far as `T` itself is copyable/moveable. So, how do you do it?

Pre-constraints, you would need to write a bunch of meta-programming hackery. Maybe you make these constructors templates, which require that the given type `U` is the same as `T`, in addition to the copy/move requirement. Or you might have to write a base class that you inherit from, which has different specializations based on the copy/moveability of `T`.

Post-constraints, you do this:

```
template<typename T>
class value
{
public:
  value(const T& t) requires is_copy_constructible_v<T> : t_(t) {}
  value(T&& t) requires is_move_constructible_v<T> : t_(std::move(t)) {}

private:
  T t_;
};
```

No hackery. No applying templates to functions that don't need to be templates. It just works, and it's easy for the user to understand what is going on.

This is especially important for functions which *cannot* be templates. In order for a constructor to be considered a copy or move constructor, it *cannot* be a template. Same goes for copy/move assignment operators. But such things can have constraints.

Answer (score 22):

Just as a concept consider the following example

```
#include <iostream>

void f( long x ) requires ( sizeof( long ) == sizeof( int ) )
{
    std::cout << "Bye " << x << '\n';
}

void f( long long x ) requires ( sizeof( long ) == sizeof( long long ) )
{
    std::cout << "Hello " << x << '\n';
}

int main() 
{
    f( 0l );
}
```

If `sizeof( long ) == sizeof( long long )` then the program output will be

```
Hello 0
```

Otherwise

```
Bye 0
```

For example you can use such an approach in a function that calculates the factorial to restrict the number of a loop iterations or to throw an exception.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

unsigned long factorial( unsigned long n ) noexcept( false ) 
    requires ( sizeof( unsigned long ) == sizeof( unsigned int ) )
{
    const unsigned long MAX_STEPS = 12;

    if ( MAX_STEPS < n ) throw std::out_of_range( "Too big value." );

    unsigned long f = 1;

    for ( unsigned long i = 1; i < n; i++ ) f *= ( i + 1 );

    return f;
}

unsigned long long factorial( unsigned long long n ) noexcept( false ) 
    requires ( sizeof( unsigned long ) == sizeof( unsigned long long ) )
{
    const unsigned long long MAX_STEPS = 20;

    if ( MAX_STEPS < n ) throw std::out_of_range( "Too big value." );

    unsigned long f = 1;

    for ( unsigned long long i = 1; i < n; i++ ) f *= ( i + 1 );

    return f;
}

int main() 
{
    unsigned long n = 20;

    try
    {
        std::cout << factorial( n ) << '\n';
    }
    catch ( const std::out_of_range &ex )
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Its output might be either

```
2432902008176640000
```

or

```
Too big value.
```

Comment: Very nice.  Now we can uplift static asserts out of the function body and make it part of the signature.

Comment: Indeed, or choose to write an overload instead of `if constexpr`

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers because they're of such high quality, but I felt that NicolBolas' answer was more in line with what the feature is for. I'm sorry that you'll just have to settle for an upvote.

Comment: @jondoe If your compiler does not compile it does not mean that the code is invalid. It means only that you do not yet understand this and nothing more.

Comment: @jondoe You need to use a more modern compiler that supports the require clause.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow is gcc 10.3 modern enough?

Comment: @jondoe If the compiler supports the require clause the code should be compiled. The code was compiled by many participants who read the answer except only you.

Comment: @jondoe It seems that when the post was written ( in 2017) the concept of the requires was different than it is now defined in the C++ 20 and compilers compiled the program.

Comment: This post should be updated, this doesn't seem to be allowed in C++20 and all the recent mainstream compilers reject it.

Answer (score 2):

As some comments pointed out, constraint on non-templated function was once introduced into some drafts, but was NOT finally accepted by C++20. This answer aims to keep the conclusions up to date.

Let's take [N4860](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf) (the final draft for C++20) as a reference. It says

```
§ 9.3 Declarators [dcl.decl]
4. The optional requires-clause (13.1) in an init-declarator or member-declarator shall be present only if the
declarator declares a templated function (9.3.3.5).
```

And the corresponding example is easier to understand:

```cpp
void f1(int a) requires true; // error: non-templated function
```

We can also easily verify that modern c++ compilers reject such usage, e.g. [gcc 12.2](https://godbolt.org/z/frYs3TesG) [clang 16.0.0](https://godbolt.org/z/r7ae1qbz8)